# How to collect numerical values within children using Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to develop an application. I can tell you I'm new to this. I want to aggregate the number values of children under a title using Firebase database. How can I achieve this?

Example Children1 = "10" Children2 = "20" I want Children1 + Children2 = 30

Comment: means you want to get total number of children under title? Right?

Comment: OR you want to add numeric value as child name?Please define.

Comment: No. Example Children 1 = "10" Children 2 = "20" I want Children1 + Children2 = 30

Comment: If you don't understand something in my answer you can ask me @Trk

Comment: hi @Trk please show my posted code and if any query feel free to ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("IndexOfYourDatabase"); //Init your ref according to your index
private int res = 0;

myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
             for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {                       
                  res += Integer.parseInt(messageSnapshot.child("").getValue().toString()); //acces to the value of every child and count them in res.
              }
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
```

Don't forget to replace `IndexOfYourDatabase` by gour Index

By this way you implement a for loop to add up the values of your children

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to calculate single values from different childrens then use below code :-**

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("database root name").child("database root field key").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                   int val1 = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("childern1").getValue().toString();
                   int val2 = Integer.parseInt(dataSnapshot.child("childern2").getValue().toString();

                   int total = val1 +val2;

                            }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

**If you want to calculate number of records,**

```
private int totalval= 0; 

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("database root name").child(database root key name).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             for (DataSnapshot innerChild : dataSnapshot.child("childern1").getChildren()) {

                            totalVal + = Integer.parseInt(innerChild.child("").getValue().toString();
                          }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: He wants to add up the value of every children so your code doesn't work because to access every child you have to provide an empty field in your child.